# Dynamic form and date format in angularjs and node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I hope you can help me I have some doubts about nodejs and angularjs, I'm just starting with this,

I am doing a project in nodejs with angularjs and I found this example of a project

```
Http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/angular_CRUD_demo/
```

my question

How can I do that to open another form within a same page as it does in the demo of the link? I hope you can explain me and my question is now about the format of the time, I am trying to get the date and now of this moment and for that use the following

```
Var datetime = require ('node-datetime');

Var date = Date.now ();
Var datenow = new Date (date);
Var date = datenow.toString ("dd-mm-yyyy HH: mm"). Replace (/ T /, '') .replace (/\..+/, '');
```

And the consula shows this as a result

```
Thu May 18 2017 12:17:59 GMT-0400 (CLT)
```

But I wish it was this way

```
2017-05-18 12:17:59
```

And the other doubt how I can make more dynamic and open a form inside another as in the demo link I leave, I hope you can help me and thank you for your time

Comment: I think you want `toISOString` instead of `toString`

Comment: Results in incorrect time

Comment: There is no preconfigured function in JavaScript to get the date in the format you want it. You have to write your own function/class to get it. Do it by using `year = date.getFullYear();` etc. and put it together in the format you like!